# How do I sample from a discrete (categorical) distribution in log space?

Tags: random-generation

Suppose I have a discrete distribution defined by the vector $\theta_0, \theta_1, ..., \theta_N$ such that category $0$ will be drawn with probability $\theta_0$ and so on. I then discover that some of the values in distribution are so small that they underflow my computer's floating point number representation, so, to compensate, I do all my calculations in log-space. Now I have a log-space vector $log(\theta_0), log(\theta_1), ..., log(\theta_N)$.

Is it possible to sample from the distribution such that the original probabilities hold (category $i$ is drawn with probability $\theta_i$) but without ever leaving log-space? In other words, how do I sample from this distribution without underflows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to sample from categorical distribution given log-probabilities *without leaving log space* using the [Gumbel-max trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution#Sampling_via_the_Gumbel_distribution). The idea is that if you are given unnormalized log-probabilities $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$, that can be translated to proper probabilities using softmax function

$$ p_i = \frac{\exp(\alpha_i)}{\sum_j \exp(\alpha_j)} $$

then to sample from such distribution you can use the fact that if $g_1,\dots,g_k \sim \mathcal{G}(0)$ are independent samples taken from standard Gumbel distribution parametrized by location $m$,

$$ F(G \le g) = \exp(-\exp(-g+m))$$

then it can be shown (see references below) that

$$ \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\begin{align}
\argmax_i \,\{\, g_i + \alpha_i \,\} &\sim \frac{\exp(\alpha_i)}{\sum_j \exp(\alpha_j)} \\
\max_i\,\{\, g_i + \alpha_i \,\} &\sim \mathcal{G}(\; \log\sum_i\exp\{\alpha_i\}\;)
\end{align}
$$

and we can take

$$
z = \argmax_i \,\{\, g_i + \alpha_i \,\}
$$

as a sample from categorical distribution parametrized by $p_1,\dots,p_k$ probabilities. This approach was described in greater detail in blog entries by  [Ryan Adams](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/blog/2013/04/06/the-gumbel-max-trick-for-discrete-distributions/) and [Laurent Dinh](https://laurent-dinh.github.io/2016/11/22/gumbel-max.html), moreover Chris J. Maddison, Daniel Tarlow and Tom Minka [gave a speach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGlMCxUcGm8) ([slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cmaddis/pubs/astartalk.pdf)) on *Neural Information Processing Systems* conference (2014) and wrote a paper titled [*A* Sampling*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0030) that generalized those ideas (see also Maddison, 2016; Maddison, Mnih and Teh, 2016; Jang and Poole, 2016), who refer to Yellott (1977) mentioning his as the one among those who first described this property.

It is pretty easy to implement it using [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337) by taking $g_i=-\log(-\log u_i)$ where $u_i$ are draws from uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. It is certainly not the most time-efficient algorithms for sampling from categorical distribution, but it let's you to stay in log-space what may be an advantage in some scenarios.

---

Maddison, C. J., Tarlow, D., & Minka, T. (2014). [A* sampling.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0030) [In:] Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems (pp. 3086-3094).

Yellott, J. I. (1977). The relationship between Luce's choice axiom, Thurstone's theory of comparative judgment, and the double exponential distribution. Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 15(2), 109-144.

Maddison, C. J., Mnih, A., & Teh, Y. W. (2016). [The Concrete Distribution: A Continuous Relaxation of Discrete Random Variables.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00712) arXiv preprint arXiv:1611.00712.

Jang, E., Gu, S., & Poole, B. (2016). [Categorical Reparameterization with Gumbel-Softmax.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01144) arXiv preprint arXiv:1611.01144.

Maddison, C. J. (2016). [A Poisson process model for Monte Carlo.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05986) arXiv preprint arXiv:1602.05986.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one common way to avoid underflow/overflow.

Let $m = \max_i \log(\theta_i)$.

Let $ \theta_i' = \exp( \log(\theta_i) - m )$.

You can sample from $\theta' = [\theta_1' , \theta_2',...]$.

Comment: This works as long as the difference between any one value and the max isn't too great---when that happens, the `exp` can lose precision, leading to distributions like [1.0, 3.45e-66, 0.0, 7.54e-121]. I'd like to hold out for some answer that is robust even in that case. But for now I'm upvoting your answer.